# How to force compiler to control value/pointer-to-value func arguments?

Tags: go

Dealing with go's funcs I discovered that one can't force the compiler to control whether I pass a value or pointer-to-value argument when using 'generic' interface{} type.

```
func f(o interface{}) {
...
}
```

The most obvious solution is to use the following modification:

```
func f(o *interface{}) {
...
}
```

Although this is successfully compiled I didn't find this step right. So, is there any means to state that I want to pass any ***pointer***?

Comment: Just wondering, why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: I just got used to strict parametrization of my code to know for sure the func signature for more profound design. I don't like when this piece of code crushes on run-time: func f (o interface{}) { // Works with the pointer } type s struct { value int } func main() { sv := s {value : 0}; f(sv) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At compile time, `interface{}`, the empty interface, is any type.

> all types implement the empty
>   interface: `interface{}` [Interface
>   types](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Interface_types)

Comment: Yep, under the current design of Go, it looks like that. Petty.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use [reflection](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/).

```
import "reflect"

func f(o interface{}) {
  if _, ok := reflect.Typeof(o).(*reflect.PtrType); !ok {
    panic("Not a pointer")
  }
  // ...
}
```

You could also consider [`unsafe.Pointer`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer), but the type information would be lost.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've done to work around the problem. However, reflection way seems to be labored and a bit crutchy. Moreover, it's useless in compile-time.